# Can't create many customer payment profile and after that purchase with multiple payment profile

Tags: php, api, authorize.net

Hi everyone can give me one suggestion about multiple credit card purchase with create customer payment profile for example i have 3 credit card info with amount and i want after save this tree profile charge but i lost amount after create profile... if we use CreateCustomerPaymentProfileRequest and save multiple payment profiles, is it going to save with the same order as we send the data, e.g.
if we have

```
request => [
    CC Info 1,
    CC Info 2,
    CC Info 3
]
```

and the response is

```
response => [
    Payment Profile Id1,
    Payment Profile Id2,
    Payment Profile Id3
],
```

can we say that

```
Payment Profile Id1 is for CC info 1,
Payment Profile Id2 is for CC Info 2,
Payment Profile Id3 is for CC Info 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Payment profile IDs are returned in the same order they were created.